# Obtaining a specific substring of a string

Tags: java, regex, substring

I was wondering if anyone could help.  I have one big string which would be similar to below:

```
Name="firstName" Description="this is a test description" date="01/01/2016".
```

What I want to do in java is to simply abstract a small part of this string, namely the bit after description which is in quotes which would ideally give me "this is a test description".  Would anyone be able to guide me on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking is `Regular Expressions`

Comment: Is this json or xml? Maybe then your problem could be solved different.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex: `.*Description=\"([\\w ]+)\".*"`. The string you want is capture group 1. For example:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*Description=\"([\\w ]+)\".*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate your input, however when I use that Reg Expression against my string it doesnt seem to return any results.  It is quite possible I am doing something wrong. I am using https://regex101.com/ to test this out.  Thanks

Comment: Each regex engine is different. Each language has its particularities. Your question is about Java, please test in a Java regex engine, not on a PHP one.

Answer (score 2):

If the string is exactly as you have there?

Let's say the string looks like this, you could use split.

```
 String description = str.split("\"")[3];
```

This will give you exactly the part between the `Description` quotation marks, with just a split. You can run it here with a [small example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ0hIZ2NJcThva2s)

As a small note: this assumes there are no `"` inside the actual content parts. (In firstname, I'm assuming this is a safe guess, but I'm not sure if the same can be said for the description part)

Comment: It will not work like this: 
str = `Name="firstName" Description="this is a test description" date="01/01/2016".` > `String description` = [`Name="firstName"`,  `Description="this`, `is`, `a`, `test`, `description"`, `date="01/01/2016".`] > `String descriptionContent` =  `"this`

Comment: @NathaëlNoguès I updated the answer, you were right :-)

Comment: Like this it will work, but I personally think this is an ugly solution; and you have to be sure that your description doesn't contains any `\"`

Comment: @NathaëlNoguès Yup, I actually said that in the last part of the post. This solution is making some assumptions about the input :-)

Comment: Valid solution of course, but IMO in this case a regex is more readable, flexible and precise.

Comment: @m0skit0 I agree and have upvoted you for that solution. It's good to see alternative solutions and get the pros/cons of them. :-)